In windows, how to change the order of networks priority to use when multiples are availables?
I have an android smartphone with USB tethering connection sharing... it's plugged to my windows PC
I have an ethernet RJ45 wire.... also plugged to my windows PC...
It uses automatically the ethernet and don't care about my mobile 4G connection sharing from my phone... How to force windows using my phone connection sharing without unplug physically the wire ethernet ?
In macOS we can change the order in system preferences but in a windows OS i didn't found it...

You are looking to change the Automatic metric value of the adapter properties
